# someone knows how to add a setup file into a setup project in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation

i have a project that also need to install other msi's files to be able to works my previous app, but i was wondering if my installer project could do all this thing in only one setup file, it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you can add merge module (msm) in the VS Setup project and not MSI files directly. You can check with msi provider if msm file is also available or not. In case msm files are not available, one of the work-around would be to include msi files in setup package and launch them using custom action. Obvious issue is that if child msi fails then you may not able to rollback entire thing cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done through prerequisites. In Visual Studio you can add them through the project properties dialog.

This requires an EXE bootstrapper. So if you want a single setup file you can try finding a tool which can include everything in a bootstrapper. Most commercial setup authoring tools can do this.